# Overview of Margins in KOMA Script/TypeArea

Tags: margins, koma-script

I am looking for some dimensions associated to page layout using the KOMA Script classes. However, I find it very difficult to find the individual commands.

Does there exist something like such an overview (source: [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Latex_layout.svg))?
[image]

Specifically, I am looking for the command for dimension that goes from the text-area to the margin. In the figure above this would be (3) + (1).

Comment: I too found the margin setting commands in the KOMA classes to be very confusing -- BCOR? typearea? DIV?! My solution was just to use the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) package which works fine with the KOMA classes (and is recommended in the KOMA documentation).

Comment: The dimensions are the same as always. typearea is only a package which calculates for this dimensions values following some typografical rules. The left margin (3+1 in your picture) is `1in + \oddsidemargin`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### With `layout` package

As @Speravir said, the `layout` package does exactly this: it prints the page layout, with all lengths. This is the best answer, since this package is part of LaTeX [tools bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/), therefore "a part of all great TeX distributions".

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

And here's the output:

[image: KOMA-Script Report Class Layout with layout package]

### With `layouts` package

The `layouts` (plural) package extends the funtionality of `layout`, allowing you to do much, much more. To begin with, you can print the page layout alone (with `\pagelayout`) or just a table with the values of the page parameters (with `\pagevalues`) — but it does much more than just that. `\pagedesign` gives a simplified version of the `layout` package's `\layout` command.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{layouts}
\begin{document}
\currentpage
\pagedesign
\end{document}
```

[image: KOMA-Script Report Class Layout with layouts package and \pagedesign]

And a combination of the commands mentioned before gives an output similar to the one given by the `layout` package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{layouts}
\begin{document}
\currentpage
\pagediagram
\pagevalues
\end{document}
```

[image: KOMA-Script Report Class Layout with layouts package and \pagediagram and \pagevalues]

Comment: Nice answer! I’d give you two upvotes, if possible.