# Combine geometry and KOMA-Script’s DIV calculation (or: Make \newgeometry only set the explictitly given values)

Tags: margins, koma-script, geometry

I wonder if it is possible to combine `geometry` and the type area calculation of KOMA-Script. I’d like to use the calculated area but set (e.g.) the top margin to 1cm, without touching the other values. The problem is that `\newgeometry` set the explicitly given values (`top=1cm`) – which is desired – but it also sets the not given values (like `bottom`, `left`, `right` etc.) to `geometry`’s defaults.

An alternative question is:
**How can I make `\newgeometry` set only the explictit given values?**

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\newgeometry{top=1cm}


\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

<sub>Please edit the question title if you can provide a better one than I do …</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid, that’s not possible. But playing around with the top lengths (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51497/9237) seems to work:

```
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrbook}
\setlength{\voffset}{0pt}
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}% hides the header line, too
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1cm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note, that this approach will fail, if you initiate a later recalculation with `\KOMAoption{DIV}{calc}` or `\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}`:

```
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrbook}
\setlength{\voffset}{0pt}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1cm}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-4]
\pagebreak
\KOMAoption{DIV}{calc} % types out a warning
\kant[5-7]
\end{document}
```

If we had used `DIV=calc` already in first state, it would work, though, as I see.

Comment: Thanks. But this’ll only work for the example with setting the top margin, I guess. How about the other margins and values like `footsep`, `marginparsep` etc.

Comment: @Tobi: I think I misunderstood you … On the other hand: Try it out yourself with the MWE!