# Reduce space between footnotes and footer without geometry

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I have the problem that I am not able to set the correct space between the footnotes and the footline. There is way too much space yet. Here is an example what it looks like:

[image]

I found an example that I can fix it with the `geometry`-package and set the footkip height using `\usepackage[footskip=8mm]{geometry}`. The problem is that loading the `geometry` package even without an option destroys my KOMA layout. Here is the layout without the loaded geometry package:

[image]

And this happens when I load the geometry package without any options:

[image]

The geometry package destroys alot of the page layout. So how else can I reduce the space between the footnote and the footnoteline? It would be perfect having a space of 1 or 1.5 lines of the height of a line of a footnote. I also tried to lower `footheight=1cm` in the document class but then I get an error that the footheight is too low.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside=false, DIV=12, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totocnumbered, headheight=1cm, footheight=1cm, numbers=autoendperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[multiple, bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Set up headers and footers
% Automark fills the \leftmark and \rightmark placeholders with the section and subsection
% Autooneside is needed by automark
\usepackage[automark, autooneside=false, headsepline, footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\leftmark}}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ofoot{\pagemark~\hspace*{1mm}} 

% Page Style for page which shall contain the page number only
\newpairofpagestyles{pagenumbersonly}{
    \ofoot{\pagemark~\hspace*{1mm}}
}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{pagenumbersonly}{oninit=\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}}

% Fixing pagestyle for pages containing \section command
\xpretocmd{\section}{\vspace*{1cm}\thispagestyle{pagenumbersonly}}{}{}

%Fixing headline for the bibliography section
\xpretocmd{\bibliography}{\ihead{\leftmark}}{}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOCUMENT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \layout
    \lipsum[10]\footnote{ABC}\lipsum{DEF}\footnote{GHI}\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

To ensure that no package inferes the layout, these are all of my used packages:

```
\usepackage[automark, autooneside=false, headsepline, footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                             
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                    
\usepackage{lmodern}                                            
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}                                   
\usepackage{microtype}                                      
\usepackage{siunitx}                                        
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                          
\usepackage{booktabs}                                           
\usepackage{graphicx}                                           
\usepackage{listings, lstautogobble}            
\usepackage{lscape}                                             
\usepackage{pdflscape}                                  
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}                                           
\usepackage{acronym}                                        
\usepackage{changepage}                                     
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}                                           
\usepackage{lipsum}                                             
\usepackage[multiple, bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51396/overview-of-margins-in-koma-script-typearea Have you read this? Just define everything with geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `\footskip` without loading package `geometry`:

```
    \setlength\footskip{30pt}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I now just have the problem that if there is a footnote, there is a space between the footnote and the text, see: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151026/cnov6xsw.png 
If there is no footnote, the text is directly over the line, without the space: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151026/th6x59cx.png
Is there a possibility to make this consistent? E.g. having the text, then there is a space of one line of the textheight, then having optionally the footnotes followed by the footsepline?

Comment: Okay, it works when I remove `footheight=1cm` from the document class. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you missunderstood here something.  First KOMA-Script does its own calculation of the typing area (`DIV=12`).  You can visualise this with package `showframe`. 
Please see too that KOMA-Script introduced a new parameter, not present without KOMA-Script: option `footheight`.

I changed your code to this MWE (deleted `footmisc` etc to show the behavior of original KOMA-Script, I added another footnote to have two on one side; please see the comments in the MWE!):

```
\documentclass[%
  paper=a4, 
  twoside=false, 
  DIV=12, 
  BCOR=5mm, 
  bibliography=totocnumbered, 
% headheight=1cm, % paper top-typing area top       % <=================
% footheight=1cm, % paper bottom-typing area bottom % <=================
  numbers=autoendperiod
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{showframe} % <=============================================
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\raggedbottom % last line can move                 % <=================
%\flushbottom  % last line always at the bottom     % <=================
%\setlength\footskip{40pt}                          % <=================


\begin{document}
  \lipsum[10]\footnote{ABC}\lipsum[1]\footnote{abc \lipsum[1]} % <======
  \lipsum{DEF}\footnote{GHI}\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

All changed lines are marked with `% <=========`.  Now please play with the comment signs in this code.  You get:

[image: Result of MWE]

Your `DIV=12` defines the top margin and the foot margin (please the the following image or compile by your own). The size of these margins shows a **pretty good typography**! That, what you think is an error, is the---for a good typography---wanted footsize of double distance of the headsize! Therefore you can see that the footnote is inside the wanted typing area.

See the third footnote:

[image]

You can play with the commands in lines 15 til 17 to change the place of the last line of the side and the `\footskip`, as mentioned in a comment/answer.
And see the changes if you uncomment lines 7 and 8 (see the resulting typing area, shown in the mwe with `showframe`).

You see, that there is no space too much, no it is good typography!  If you change `footskip` you change the good balance of typing area and footline.

You can use KOMA-Script to change the layout of the footnotes, if you want.